# Packer 'Unsupported attribute' when trying to use variable from variables file

Tags: packer

I'm new to Packer and I'm seeing the following error when trying to running 'packer build' when trying to use variables from a ***.auto.pkvars.hcl** file.

The 'packer build' will work fine if I hardcode the '**instance_type**' setting by removing **var.instance_type**.

Please see template and variable files below error.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on packer-build.pkr.hcl line 17:
  (source code not available)

This object does not have an attribute named "instance_type".
```

**packer-build.pr.hcl**

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    amazon = {
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/amazon"
      version = "~> 1.2.1"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  timestamp = regex_replace(timestamp(), "[- TZ:]", "")
}

source "amazon-ebs" "demo" {

  region                      = "us-east-2"
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  force_deregister            = true
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  communicator                = "ssh"
  ssh_username                = "ec2-user"

  # new custom ami
  ami_name                    = "testami-${local.timestamp}"
  ami_description             = "test ami"
  ami_virtualization_type     = "hvm"
  ami_regions                 = ["us-east-2"]



  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      name                  = "al2023-*.*-x86_64"
      virtualization-type   = "hvm"
      root-device-type      = "ebs"
    }

    owners                  = ["137112412989"]
    most_recent             = true

  }
}

build {
    sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.demo"]

    provisioner "shell" {
      inline = ["echo test"]
    }
}
```

**variables.auto.pkrvars.hcl**

```
instance_type               = "t2.micro"
base_ami_region             = "us-east-2"
...
}
```

Comment: What is the variable declaration block?

Comment: I do not have a variable block in the template (as seen above) as I was trying to store all variables in the *.auto.pkrvars.hcl file.

Comment: Does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76584092/13567897) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is missing variable declaration

> In the HCL2 Packer templates, we must always pre-define our variables
> in the HCL equivalent of the "variables" stanza.

Add the following to your packer-build.pr.hcl file

```
variable "instance_type" {}
# and base_ami_region if you want to use it in hcl file
variable "base_ami_region" {}
```

More details can be found here:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/guides/hcl/variables